# My index.php file is showing all pages on my site at once

Tags: php, web, indexing

I am using an index.php file to include the header, navigation and footer on all pages on my site, however I have an issue with my php which is showing all pages within the pages folder at once, rather than just showing the page I'm currently on.

Here is the PHP I am using, any advice would be appreciated!

```
<?php
$files = scandir( __DIR__ . '/pages' );

unset( $files[0] );
unset( $files[1] );

foreach($files as $file){
    include __DIR__ . '/pages/' . $file;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're using scandir to get a list of all the pages. Then looping through the list and including them all. Not sure what you expect to happen? How are you identifying which page you're on?

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: welp, it's not just including, it's also executing your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Then just remove the whole script and use `<?php include('yourDesiredfile.php'); ?>` for the files you would like to include.